# adding a table border when * is defined with border:0

Tags: css

What is the best way to add a border to an html table when I already have a rule in the css

```
*{border:0;}
```

If I add style="border:1px;" into the table then I just get a border surrounding the entire table instead of for each cell as well which is what I should have when I use:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table
{
border-collapse:collapse;
}
table, td, th
{
border:1px solid black;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zKCHB/)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use that HTML as it is not valid. use the following CSS:

```
table {
border: 1px;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td, table th {
border: 1px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

`border-collapse` on `collapse` makes the borders of the cells single. That is the equivalent of HTML cellspacing. Make sure you set the border on the `table` as well as the `td` and `th`.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set borders on cells.  Perhaps you should set up a CSS class for this table.

```
table.bordered
{
border-collapse:collapse;
}
table.bordered > td
{
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Then you would use `<table class="bordered">`

edit: The other answers assume you want this for ALL tables.  I see no reason to jump to that conclusion.